# OpenPyXL - Is it possible to add a Input message to a data validation list?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet (.xlsm) that gets generated using openpyxl. A number of fields are dropdown menus which are generated using the following code

```
#function to add validation drop down menu within xlsm file
def addValidationDropDown(sheet,formulaLocation,dropdownLocation):
    dataVal = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=formulaLocation)
    sheet.add_data_validation(dataVal)
    dataVal.add(dropdownLocation)
```

Which works fine, however, for each column that has a dropdown i want to add a input message like this

[image]

Is it possible to add a input message on a datavalidation object within openpyxl, it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.1/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation.showInputMessage), but it seems its just a bool.

here is the popup input message within excel
[image]

Comment: That looks like a comment on the cell and not related to data validation. But, if in doubt, check the source of the worksheet file.

Comment: @CharlieClark its the input message from the data validation (pic added in question). The reason I had to do the data validation was because openpyxl was not keeping the dropdown list, so I had to create it within openpyxl. But now its lost the input message

Comment: Try the `prompt` attribute and check the OOXML specification for further details.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark prompt did it.Add it as an answer and ill mark it as answered. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charlie Clark, works for me even in the old OpenPyXl version
'promptTitle' can be skipped, but not 'prompt'

```
data_val_hint = DataValidation()
valRange = "A1:A10"
data_val_hint.prompt = 'hint'
data_val_hint.ranges.append(valRange)
worksheet.add_data_validation(data_val_hint)
```